# react-infinite-scroll-component stopped working suddenly

Tags: reactjs

So, I am having a very unusual issue. I am using the package react-infinite-scroll-component and it worked perfectly before and suddenly stopped working. I have not imported anything new on the page and have stopped working now. I remember it worked perfectly.
These are the imports on the page:

````
```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Col, Row, Icon, Spin, Radio, Tabs ,Button, Pagination } from 'antd';
import Select, { SelectOption } from '../../../shared/components/uielements/select';
import Box from '../../../shared/components/utility/box';
import LayoutWrapper from '../../../shared/components/utility/layoutWrapper.js';
import Form from '../../../shared/components/uielements/form';
import ActiveProductionClass from './active_production';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { productionByStatus } from '../../actions/edit_production_actions';
// import { Button } from 'antd/lib/radio';
import _ from "lodash";
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';
````

```
This is my package.json file:

````
```
"dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.0.3",
    "antd-local-icon": "^0.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "azure-storage": "^2.8.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "clone": "^2.1.1",
    "cluster": "^0.7.7",
    "dnd-core": "^6.0.0",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "google-map-react": "^1.0.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "html-to-draftjs": "^1.3.0",
    "image-to-base64": "^2.0.1",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.6.6",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jspdf": "git://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF.git#76edb3387cda3d5292e212765134b06150030364",
    "lodash.flow": "^3.5.0",
    "net-cluster": "0.0.2",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "nuka-carousel": "^4.2.1",
    "password-validator": "^4.0.0",
    "phantom-html-to-pdf": "^0.5.6",
    "postcss-inline-rtl": "^0.9.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "query-string": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.10.0",
    "react-carousel-slider": "^2.0.11",
    "react-cookies": "^0.1.0",
    "react-cropper": "^1.0.1",
    "react-customizable-carousel": "0.0.7",
    "react-detect-offline": "^2.1.1",
    "react-dnd": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dock": "^0.2.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.12.12",
    "react-drag-and-drop": "^2.4.0",
    "react-grid-gallery": "^0.4.11",
    "react-image-crop": "^3.0.11",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^4.1.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.3.0",
    "react-loading-components": "^1.1.12",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.1.2",
    "react-pdf": "^3.0.5",
    "react-placeholder": "^2.0.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.2.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router-navigation-prompt": "^1.8.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.5",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "react-sidebar": "^2.3.2",
    "react-sliding-pane": "^2.0.2",
    "react-smooth-scrollbar": "^8.0.6",
    "react-soundplayer": "^1.0.4",
    "react-textarea-count": "^1.0.3",
    "react-throttle": "^0.3.0",
    "react-truncate": "^2.3.0",
    "react-window-size-listener": "^1.0.10",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "repl": "^0.1.3",
    "reqwest": "^2.0.5",
    "simple-react-validator": "0.0.7",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.2.5",
    "styled-components": "^2.2.1",
    "styled-theme": "^0.3.3",
    "video-react": "^0.10.4",
    "yargs": "^11.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-alice-carousel": "^1.10.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.4.0"
  },
```
````

I am rendring it like this:

```

```
return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={this.state.activeProduction_data.length} //This is important field to render the next data
      next={this.loadMore}
      hasMore={true}
      loader={<Spin spinning={this.state.loading} tip="Loading..." indicator={antIcon} delay={500} size="large"></Spin>}
      endMessage={
        <p style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
          <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
        </p>
      }

      >
      <Spin spinning={this.state.loading} tip="Loading..." indicator={antIcon} delay={500} size="large">
            <LayoutWrapper>
              <Box>
                <Form>
                  <Row style={rowStyle} gutter={gutter} justify="start">
                    <Col md={24} sm={24} xs={24} >
                      <Tabs defaultActiveKey={this.state.defaultKey} onChange={this.typeChange} tabBarExtraContent={operations}>
                        <TabPane tab="LIVE" key="1"></TabPane>
                        <TabPane tab="DRAFT" key="2"></TabPane>
                        <TabPane tab="ARCHIVED" key="3"></TabPane>
                      </Tabs>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>

                  <Row style={rowStyle} gutter={gutter} justify="start">
                    {this.state.activeProduction_data.length > 0 ?
                      <ActiveProductionClass onArchiveClick={this.onArchiveClick} /* onCardClick={this.onCardClick} */ activeProductionData={this.state.activeProduction_data} />
                      : <div style={{ textAlign: "center", width: "100%" }}>{this.state.selected_type == 1 ? 'No Live Productions.' : ''}{this.state.selected_type == 2 ? 'No Draft Productions.' : ''}{this.state.selected_type == 3 ? 'No Archived Productions.' : ''}</div>}
                  </Row>
                </Form>

              </Box>

            </LayoutWrapper>
            </Spin>
</InfiniteScroll>

    );
```

```
I have removed everything from the page and tried the one you gave in the example and I checked that nothing was still working. Does anyone have any idea which of the package is hindering with the performance?

I tried a little troubleshooting and checked that the package works but the `loadmore` function is not being called. I say this because the property `loader={<Spin spinning={this.state.loading} tip="Loading..." indicator={antIcon} delay={500} size="large"></Spin>}` in `Infinitescroller` works as i can see the spin on page. But when i scroll down on the page the `loadmore` function should call which is not getting called now and was working fine before.

Please help me guys! thanks!!!